# Conditional Select - Part 2

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following situation within a PL/SLQ function. Depending of existing table field value I might run a different select. Specifically: I can have multiple rows for a particular BILL CODE (PINGPONG) where I would only need to get the SYS_FIELD value. This field has to be fetched only once according to following condition: If fields prep_seq_num=0 and primary_ind=0 then just get this row sys_field value straightaway and do not take care of other possible prep_seq_num and primary_ind values different from 0. If that rows is not existing, fetch the sys_field value from prep_seq_num!=0 and primary_ind=1. For both case only one instance/row must be possible So in the first case I should run:

```
SELECT SYS_FIELD
      INTO v_start_of_invoice
      FROM BILL
     WHERE TRACKING_ID = v_previous_trackingID
       AND BSCO_CODE_ID = 'PINGPONG'
       AND CHRG_ACCT_ID = v_ACCT_ID
       AND PREP_SEQ_NUM = 0 -- maybe not needed here
       AND ITEM_CAT_CODE_ID=1
       AND PARTITION_KEY = v_prev_partition
       AND SUBPARTITION_KEY = v_prev_subpartition
       AND PRIMARY_IND=0;
In the second case

SELECT SYS_FIELD
      INTO v_start_of_invoice
      FROM BILL
     WHERE TRACKING_ID = v_previous_trackingID
       AND BILL_CODE_ID = 'PINGPONG'
       AND ITEM_CAT_CODE_ID in ('5' , '-100')
       AND PARTITION_KEY = v_prev_partition
       AND SUBPARTITION_KEY = v_prev_subpartition
       AND PRIMARY_IND=1;
```

Not sure I'm making it very complicated, but still I 'd need to know whether IF THEN ELSE or CASE or whatever should be used and how.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize an implicit cursor for loop.

```
for rec IN ( <your query that gives all records) 
LOOP

--compare the value of this variable and decide in the IF condition.

    IF rec.prep_seq_num=0 and rec.primary_ind=0
      THEN
    -- write the query to get the sys_field 

     ELSE 
    -- write alternative query.

    END IF;

END LOOP;
```